# How to configure eb cli for team for deployment from more than one user?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed the django application on aws . I want that application should be deployed by team as well. What is procedure to do this? I have searched a lot and almost spent couple of hours . Anyone has any answer or tutorial?

Can we share these keys ?

```
aws_access_key_id
aws_secret_access_key
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the AWS access keys should be kept secret and not even stored under version control.

For deployment (i.e. the credentials needed to actually release the code - used by EB), you should use an aws profile. Add a ~/.aws/credentials file with

```
[myprofile]
aws_access_key_id=...
aws_secret_access_key=...
```

and then, on all eb commands use --profile. e.g.

```
eb create --profile myprofile
```

If your application requires other AWS services (e.g. RDS, S3, SQS), then you can use the same local profile for development (although I would recommend not requiring any other AWS for testing) by using then environment variable `export AWS_PROFILE=myprofile`. And then rely on AWS roles and policies for the production environment.

If you feel you need the secret keys as django settings, then consider using https://django-environ.readthedocs.org where you can keep all those secrets on a .env file that gets loaded by django. But again, this file should not be under version control.

You should also create IAM users for every person in your team, so each person has its own credentials, and you can more easily monitor or if needed, revoke credentials.

Comment: Can you give me any link to do this or anyone has already had this kind of problem ?

Comment: Which part? There is a lot of documentation on the AWS site on how to use profiles. Google "AWS eb  profiles"

Comment: Assign already deployed application to newly created IAM user , so that he would able to make changes and able to deploy the application,    do you have some documentation for that.

Comment: The production servers should not need IAM users as they should already be using IAM roles ( eb creates one ), so the IAM users are only required on local setups to be able to communicate with AWS (e.g. To do 'EB deploy'). But you have not described much so I don't know if you are using AWS secret keys for something in your production server.

Comment: ,As I am the only person who deploys the code , and I have to give access to others, I have that file in                                                                                        ~/.aws/credentials file . I am not commiting this file to git or production server.

Comment: Then what's your question? You asked if credentials should be shared and the answer is No. If you want to ask something more specific, please describe it in detail maybe with code snippets

Comment: What do I do so that my whole devops/developement team able to deploy their code? As i don't know how to give access to them .

Comment: You create IAM users for each of them with only permissions to what you want them to access. And then you have them each store the credentials on their .aws/credentials.

Comment: Thanks @davka . This helped me